# Usefulness of Z-normalization in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, normality-assumption

*Z*-normalization means rescaling the feature $X$ by subtracting the average $\mu$ and dividing by its standard deviation $\sigma$, i.e., $(X-\mu)/\sigma$.

What is the usefulness of normalizing data for machine learning?

Comment: You may wanna look at this for implications of normalization in different ML tasks  http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html

Comment: One point that the link does not mention is the representation of continuous numbers using discrete ones.  there is denser representation around 1.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point